# Changing font in a Console window in C#

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, console

I have a program, written in C#, that uses characters not available in Raster fonts. So I want to change font to Lucida Console.

To change Console font programatically, I use SetCurrentConsoleFontEx() with this code (Source: [MSDN Console Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console.aspx)) but I got an System.AccessViolationException on call SetCurrentConsoleFontEx().

Could anyone help me?

Thank's for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleExtender 
{
  public static class ConsoleHelper
  {
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
      {
          internal uint cbSize;
          internal uint nFont;
          internal COORD dwFontSize;
          internal int FontFamily;
          internal int FontWeight;
          internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
      }

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      internal struct COORD
      {
          internal short X;
          internal short Y;

          internal COORD(short x, short y)
          {
              X = x;
              Y = y;
          }
      }
      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
      static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
             IntPtr consoleOutput,
             bool maximumWindow,
             ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
             IntPtr consoleOutput,
             bool maximumWindow,
             CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX consoleCurrentFontEx);

      private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
      private const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 4;
      private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
      private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

      public static void SetConsoleFont(string fontName = "Lucida Console") 
      {
          unsafe
          {
            IntPtr hnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            if (hnd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX info = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);

                // Set console font to Lucida Console.
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX newInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                newInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(newInfo);
                newInfo.FontFamily = TMPF_TRUETYPE;
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(newInfo.FaceName);
                Marshal.Copy(fontName.ToCharArray(), 0, ptr, fontName.Length);

                // Get some settings from current font.
                newInfo.dwFontSize = new COORD(info.dwFontSize.X, info.dwFontSize.Y);
                newInfo.FontWeight = info.FontWeight;
                SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, newInfo);
            }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

There's two problems with the way you've defined those API calls.

First, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` says:

> `lpConsoleCurrentFontEx`
>
> A ***pointer*** to a `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` structure that contains the font information.

So the third parameter needs to be passed by reference:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
    IntPtr consoleOutput,
    bool maximumWindow,
    ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX consoleCurrentFontEx);
```

and you need to call the method like this:

```
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref newInfo);
```

Secondly, the `FaceName` field in the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX` structure is an array of *Unicode* characters. I had to specify the `CharSet` to get it to work:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
{
    internal uint cbSize;
    internal uint nFont;
    internal COORD dwFontSize;
    internal int FontFamily;
    internal int FontWeight;
    internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this works but if you go to Properties -> Build and disable "Prefer 32-bit", you won't get the error any more.

Answer (score 0):

I got only one solution of this problem, got to the build open plateform target and select the dropdown to Any cpu then it will definetly work

Answer (score -1):

Based on hints of thirdwaffle/reduckted? above, I managed to get it to work,
on my Vista machine.  Definitely does *not* work on XP.

```
/*

  Purpose: Set a TrueType font in the Windows command window, in order that
           multinational characters have a fighting chance of being readable.


  Usage: This should only work on Windows Vista or Server 2008 and later.
         To check, use the 'ver' command and disallow the strings " 2000 ",
         " 2003 ", and " XP ".  Or allow only the strings " 6." and "10.".
         One way to do it is using the DOS commands:
         ver | findstr /r /c:"\[[^ ]*  *[16]" > "%TEMP%\nul"
         if errorlevel 1 goto skipfont

         If OK, use:
            askufont [/d] FONTNAME
         Here /d, if present, turns on debug mode.

         Return status: If the errorlevel is zero, supposedly *some* Truetype
                        font has been set.

         To see whether, say, font Consolas has really been set and not, say,
         font "Lucida Console", use:
            askufont Consolas
            if errorlevel 1 goto err
            askufont /d Consolas | find "Got font name: Consolas"
            if errorlevel 1 goto err

         askufont /?: displays help info on standard error.
         askufont /.: returns errorlevel 175.
         askufont /!: writes "askufont.cs by Leon van Dommelen v1" to standard
                      output (not standard error) and returns errorlevel 177.
                      Subsequent backward-compatible version numbers can be
                      appended to v1 (e.g. v12 for version 2).

  Copyright: Copyright 2017 Leon van Dommelen.  This software is made
             available under the GNU Public License version 3.
             There is no warrantee of any kind on this free software.

             This originated from
                https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console.aspx
             but that did not work.

             I got error corrections from "thirdwaffle" in the thread
                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631634/
                changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-c-sharp
             In particular, the last argument of SetCurrentConsoleFont was
             corrected to a pointer just like in GetCurrentConsoleFont.  And
             the charset in CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX was changed to Unicode.

             After that, it still did not work.  Turned out to be bad values
             for the newInfo buffer below. I got values that actually work
             (for me) from
                http://www.janthor.com/sketches/index.php?/archives/19-How-
                to-change-the-font-of-the-Windows-console-with-Python.html
             He lists:
                TERMINAL = Font(9, 10, 18, 48, 400, "Terminal")
                CONSOLAS = Font(9, 8, 18, 54, 400, "Consolas")
                LUCIDA = Font(12, 11, 18, 54, 400, "Lucida Console")
                LUCIDA14 = Font(12, 8, 14, 54, 400, "Lucida Console")
             The key is that the font family *must* be 54, not just the
             TT bit of it.

             Finally, I rewrote it all to make it more usable and changeable.

  Make: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe/unsafe askufont.cs

*/

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class SetTTFont
{

    // Import GetStdHandle to get a handle on the terminal output.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    // Import GetCurrentConsoleFontEx for current font info.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        IntPtr consoleOutput,
        bool maximumWindow,
        ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

    // Import SetCurrentConsoleFontEx to change the font.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        IntPtr consoleOutput,
        bool maximumWindow,
        ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

    // Define descriptive names for some constants.
    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    private const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 4;
    private const int FONT_FAMILY = 54;
    private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
    private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

    public static unsafe int Main( string[] args )
    {
        // whether we are in debug mode
        bool debug = false;
        // handle on standard output
        IntPtr hnd;
        // old and new console information structures
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX oldInfo, newInfo, setInfo;
        // converted char[] string
        string str;
        // argument index
        int i;

        // process arguments
        for (i=0; i<args.Length; i++) {
            if (args[i].Length < 1) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("*** askufont: Nil argument {0}", i+1);
                Console.Error.WriteLine("    Enter askufont /? for help.");
                return 2;
            }
            if (args[i][0] != '/') {
                break;
            }
            if (args[i].Length != 2 || args[i][0] != '/') {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
                            "*** askufont: Bad option {0}: {1}", i+1, args[i]);
                Console.Error.WriteLine("    Enter askufont /? for help.");
                return 2;
            }
            if (args[i][1] == 'd' || args[i][1] == 'D') {
                debug = true;
            }
            else if (args[i][1] == '?') {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"              askufont is Copyright 2017 Leon van Dommelen.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"  This software is made available under the GNU Public License version 3.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"         There is no warrantee of any kind on this free software.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"Usage: askufont [/d] FONTNAME");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"Tries to set a TrueType console font.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"/d: Output debug information.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"FONTNAME: a TrueType font name like \"Lucida Console\" or Consolas.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"Works for Windows Vista and later only; in the output of the VER command,");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"disallow the strings \" 2000 \", \" 2003 \", and \" XP \" using FIND.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"See the askufont.cs source for more details.");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
"Version: Leon van Dommelen 1.");
                return 2;
            }
            else if(args[i][1] == '.') {
                return 175;
            }
            else if(args[i][1] == '!') {
                Console.WriteLine("askufont.cs by Leon van Dommelen v1");
                return 177;
            }
            else {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(
                            "*** askufont: Bad option {0}: {1}", i+1, args[i]);
                Console.Error.WriteLine("    Enter askufont /? for help.");
                return 2;
            }
        }

        // Check the font argument.
        if (i > args.Length-1) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("*** askufont: Missing font name.");
            Console.Error.WriteLine("    Enter askufont /? for help.");
            return 2;
        }
        if (i < args.Length-1) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("*** askufont: Misplaced font name.");
            Console.Error.WriteLine("    Enter askufont /? for help.");
            return 2;
        }
        if (debug) Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                         "Requested Font: {0}", args[i]);

        // get a handle on standard output
        hnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        if (hnd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                   "*** askufont: Unable to get a handle on standard output!");
            return 2;
        }

        // First determine the current font information.
        oldInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();
        oldInfo.cbSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(oldInfo);
        if (!GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref oldInfo)) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                      "*** askufont: Unable to get console font information!");
            return 2;
        }
        if (debug) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                               "Old font info block size: {0}", oldInfo.cbSize);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Old font font number: {0}", oldInfo.nFont);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "Old font width:  {0}", oldInfo.dwFontSize.X);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "Old font height: {0}", oldInfo.dwFontSize.Y);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Old font family: {0}", oldInfo.FontFamily);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Old font weight: {0}", oldInfo.FontWeight);
            str = new string(oldInfo.FaceName);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Old font name: {0}", str);
        }

        // Set generic data for the new font, taking some from the old font.
        newInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();
        newInfo.cbSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(newInfo);
        newInfo.nFont = 0;
        newInfo.FontFamily = FONT_FAMILY;
        IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(newInfo.FaceName);
        Marshal.Copy(args[i].ToCharArray(), 0, ptr, args[i].Length);
        newInfo.dwFontSize=new COORD(oldInfo.dwFontSize.X,oldInfo.dwFontSize.Y);
        newInfo.FontWeight = oldInfo.FontWeight;
        if (debug) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                               "New font info block size: {0}", newInfo.cbSize);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("New font font number: {0}", newInfo.nFont);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "New font width:  {0}", newInfo.dwFontSize.X);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "New font height: {0}", newInfo.dwFontSize.Y);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("New font family: {0}", newInfo.FontFamily);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("New font weight: {0}", newInfo.FontWeight);
            str = new string(newInfo.FaceName);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("New font name: {0}", str);
        }

        // Try setting the new font.
        SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref newInfo);
        setInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();
        setInfo.cbSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(setInfo);
        if (!GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref setInfo)) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                      "*** askufont: Unable to get the new font information!");
            return 2;
        }
        if (debug) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                               "Got font info block size: {0}", setInfo.cbSize);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Got font font number: {0}", setInfo.nFont);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "Got font width:  {0}", setInfo.dwFontSize.X);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                                  "Got font height: {0}", setInfo.dwFontSize.Y);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Got font family: {0}", setInfo.FontFamily);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Got font weight: {0}", setInfo.FontWeight);
            str = new string(setInfo.FaceName);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Got font name: {0}", str);
        }

        // Check that at least we have a TT font now.
        if ((setInfo.FontFamily & TMPF_TRUETYPE) != TMPF_TRUETYPE) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(
                               "*** askufont: Error setting a TrueType font!");
            return 2;
        }

        // Done.
        return 0;
    }

    // Define the COORD structure.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct COORD
    {
        internal short X;
        internal short Y;

        internal COORD(short x, short y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    // Define the CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX structure.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX
    {
        internal uint cbSize;
        internal uint nFont;
        internal COORD dwFontSize;
        internal int FontFamily;
        internal int FontWeight;
        internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
    }
}
```

if it is any help.  Compilation instructions are in the code.  Needs Microsoft.Net version 4.