# Set console font size example

Tags: console

I want to change console font size on windows. I figured out it should be done with SetCurrentConsoleFontEx but i don't know how.

would appreciate if you provide an example.
Thanks.

Comment: I actually did. I want to perform it with c or c++

Comment: If I didn't search how do I know it should be done with SetCurrentConsoleFontE function?!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Font in a Console window in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20631634/62576)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple...Start cmd, right click on title, go to properties, than go to fonts and than you will see this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbBtX.png)

And than change font size value and thats that :)

Answer (score -1):

On windows 7 
CMD window->Right Click CMD icon (upper left corner)->Properties->Font

Comment: This question is asking about changing the font from **code**, not from a standard console window. (Note the reference to `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.) If it was about just doing what you've said, the question would be off-topic here and should be flagged as such instead of answering it.