# how to convert decimal to any UTF8 character?

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, console, ascii

I have to write a program in c# which would take a decimal integer as an input and convert/encode it to a UTF8 character and output it. For example:

input: 960

output: π

i wrote this much using various code snippets i found on the internet:

```
        int dec;
        dec = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] decBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        decBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(dec);

        String s = utf8.GetString(decBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

it works fine with the first 127 symbols (which is i assume ascii table) but with others i get boxes with question marks as output.

Correct me if i'm wrong, but as far as i understand `utf8.GetString` converts each single byte in `numberBytes` into a ascii character. However i need to **convert all of the bytes into a single utf8 character**.

Any advice how to do it?

Comment: The problem sounds like the default console font not supporting characters > 127. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631634/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

960 - is UTF16 or UTF32 code of your symbol:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(960);
{byte[4]}
    [0]: 192
    [1]: 3
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0

Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("π")
{byte[4]}
    [0]: 192
    [1]: 3
    [2]: 0
    [3]: 0

Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes("π")
{byte[2]}
    [0]: 3
    [1]: 192

Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("π")
{byte[2]}
    [0]: 207
    [1]: 128
```

UTF-8 works in other way. You can read wikipedia, for example.

Comment: oh. so what i get are bytes encoded in unicode. Then how do i convert them to UTF8?

Comment: @Yokubasu What do you mean by convert yo UTF8? You need UTF8 bytes? Or UTF8 string? If you need string, you don't have to touch UTF8 at all. You just convert your bytes to string by using UTF32 encoding.

Comment: i need both i think

Comment: @Yokubasu `Encoding.UTF32.GetString(your_4_bytes)` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF32.GetString(your_4_bytes))`

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but it seems to only work with up to 1418 characters??