# Console Font changing doesn't work

Tags: c#, fonts, console

I am currently developing a console application in c#. In this application I need to change the Console Font programmatically, because I am using the German Umlaute (ä,ö,ü) and the standard font can't visualize them.
I was looking through MSlib and stackoverflow and found the following pages:
[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

[2] [Changing font in a Console window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631634/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-c-sharp)

So I copied the solutions in my c#-program and I can compile it w/o errors, but the code doesn't change the font to Lucida. I hope that you can help me.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Main
{
//From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
//From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631634/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-c-sharp
//ConsoleFont changing
    public class ConsoleHelper
    {
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
        {
            internal uint cbSize;
            internal uint nFont;
            internal COORD dwFontSize;
            internal int FontFamily;
            internal int FontWeight;
            internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
        }

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      internal struct COORD
      {
          internal short X;
          internal short Y;

          internal COORD(short x, short y)
          {
              X = x;
              Y = y;
          }
      }
      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
      static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
             IntPtr consoleOutput,
             bool maximumWindow,
             ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        IntPtr consoleOutput,
        bool maximumWindow,
        ref CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX consoleCurrentFontEx);

      private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
      private const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 4;
      private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
      private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

      public static void SetConsoleFont(string fontName = "Lucida Console") 
      {
          unsafe
          {
            IntPtr hnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            if (hnd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX info = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);

                // Set console font to Lucida Console.
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX newInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                newInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(newInfo);
                newInfo.FontFamily = TMPF_TRUETYPE;
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(newInfo.FaceName);
                Marshal.Copy(fontName.ToCharArray(), 0, ptr, fontName.Length);

                // Get some settings from current font.
                newInfo.dwFontSize = new COORD(info.dwFontSize.X, info.dwFontSize.Y);
                newInfo.FontWeight = info.FontWeight;
                SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, ref newInfo);
            }
          }
      }
    }

//Main Program
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Encoding for Umlaute
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            //Test in Color
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            //Reset Console Color
            Console.ResetColor();
            //Title
            Console.Title = "Test";
            //Setting Font for UTF-8-Encoding
            ConsoleHelper.SetConsoleFont();
            //Main Code...
            //...
            //...
        }
    }
```

Did I make a mistake or do I need further things to be done?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The standard Console font can definitely show umlauted vowels etc. but there is an issue with the default codepage - you could try changing `Console.OutputEncoding`.

Comment: After changing the line to      Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;  it can display the ä,ö,ü and µ, but the ³ is still not displayed properly. But I can handle that. Thank You! But still I would love to know, why the code doesn't work.

Comment: `³` isn't present in the standard console font - so that would need Lucida. The code you've pasted looks ok, can't see anything obviously wrong with it

Comment: but why doesn't it change the font at the start of the program? Is my call wrong?    ConsoleHelper.SetConsoleFont();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dylan said, all I had to da was changing **"Console.OutputEncoding"**.

I still can't change the font, but that is no problem for me.

```
//Main Program
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Encoding for Umlaute
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        //Code...
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```